# How to remove a div without its content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in removing a div without its content. I have this html structure:

```
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="test">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="test">Menu 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">Menu 3</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 4</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove the div containing the class "wrap". I desire a structure like this, only without "wrap":

```
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="test">Menu 1</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 2</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 3</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 4</div>
</div>
```

I tried with this jquery:

```
$("button").click(function () {
$(".test").not().siblings().unwrap();
});
```

and with this:

```
var content = $(".wrap").html();
$(".wrap").remove();
$("body").append(content);
```

with the second one I reach my target but I lost the DOM order. How can I fix it?

Comment: Changing `$("body").append(content);` to `$('#mainWrap').prepend(content);` should do it

Comment: You can use like : $(document).ready(function(){
 var ctn = $('#mainWrap .wrap').html();
    $('.wrap').remove();
    $('#mainWrap').prepend(ctn)
});

Comment: `mainWrap.firstChild.outerHTML = mainWrap.firstChild.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w = $('.wrap').html();
  $('.wrap').remove();
  $('#mainWrap').prepend(w);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="test">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="test">Menu 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">Menu 3</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".wrap .test").unwrap('.wrap');
```

```css
.wrap {background: red;}
```

```html
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="test">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="test">Menu 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">Menu 3</div>
  <div class="test">Menu 4</div>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ by using the matching parent selector